# is there a "small font" logic in HTML / SVG? (W3C)

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a logic to switch to "small fonts" that render better, when in small sizes?

I know, that I can do something like that with JavaScript (jQuery or other), but that isn't the question.

The question is: Is there (for example in CSS) method to tell a browser to switch to "small font typeface" if displayed size < 6px (or so)?

Comment: Ehm, you mean switch to a _different_ font when at smaller sizes?

Comment: I don't think there's a native method to do it based on rendered font size but you could probably use media queries or some other CSS/DOM scripting strategy if you know the conditions under which the tiny fonts are triggered.

Comment: As Will notes, you'll have to back up a step and figure out what's causing the font to be so small. Once you identify the trigger, you can develop a strategy that responds to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't such an option natively in CSS/HTML, but there are a few mechanics you could implement yourself:

1. If you have two fonts (a default an a smaller variant) you could add a class on the `body` tag to switch between `font-family`
2. A similar approach is to have all `font-size`s expressed in `em` units and then use a class on the `body` tag to set the "root" em value. The default is 1.
3. In case the `font-size`s aren't expressed in `em` units, you could still ue the class and then use inheritance selectors to override the font-sizes. This isn't an approach I would recommend using plain CSS.

To be complete and to make these approaches easier, you could use a CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS. Define the font-size as a variable and generate two CSS files, one for each font-size. Ofcourse, you should only duplicate the CSS rules that affect the `font-size`.

Comment: anser: no there is not; I just didn't want to script something the standard already is able to. THX

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: Is there (for example in CSS) method to tell a browser to switch to "small font typeface" if displayed size < 6px (or so)?

Based on the question, it seems like you'd know if the font size is a certain size. At some point, via CSS or JS, you'd have to set the font size. At the point of applying the `font-size`, you could apply the new `font-family` as well.

That said, if you have set that font size, you could use media queries (both horizontal and vertical) to change the `font-family` as well as `font-size`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jdzv/)**

As Will and Stephen commented above, you'll need to use your Developer Tools to figure out where the font-size is being applied.